# Add existing attachment in visualforce Email template via workflow

Tags: workflow, controller, visualforce-component, vf-email-template, emailfileattachment

I have a scenario that when billing is generated in system. Invoice should be send through mail to Person Account Email. I am doing this via workflow. In workflow I have a VF email template which contain component that have all related data like name, address. that has already done. **but problem is related to attachment I am not able to attach existing attachment in email template.** attachment is already generated via DDPs. I want to avoid create new component with data and render as pdf.

**Is there any way to add existing attachment to email via workflow.**
Please anyone Guide me for the Answer.